# Decrementing product price after certain interval in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello all I am developing an auction application in Codeigniter and but I am stuck with Reverse Auction.
The issue is that I have to decrease the bidding price of every project after a certain interval at product page where all the products are being displayed but I am not able to that I also got some suggestion for creating Event Scheduler in MySQL but its also not solving my purpose so kindly suggest me some solution as I am near to deadline

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to run a cronjob for that.

With cronjob you can execute a script with an interval.
Your hosting service provider might have more information on this subject on its website/control panel.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronjob) is some more information about cron

In Codeigniter you can even call a function with an url using a cronjob